# How to pull out list of domains from Get-CsTenantFederationConfiguration

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Hope everyone's well and can give me a bit of a hand.
Via MicrosoftTeams Module, I'm running the below command.

```
Get-CsTenantFederationConfiguration
```

The output I get is as per below (I've edited out the allowed domains):

```
Identity                                    : Global
AllowedDomains                              : domain=domain.com, domain=domain1.com, domain=dc.com
BlockedDomains                              : {}
AllowFederatedUsers                         : True
AllowPublicUsers                            : True
AllowTeamsConsumer                          : False
AllowTeamsConsumerInbound                   : True
TreatDiscoveredPartnersAsUnverified         : False
SharedSipAddressSpace                       : False
RestrictTeamsConsumerToExternalUserProfiles : False
```

I can pipe the command via '| select AllowedDomains' to only show me the domains but I want to extract those domains out onto separate lines.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Really appreciate any help you can provide!
Best
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command-

> Get-CsTenantFederationConfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty
> AllowedDomains

Information is returned for all the allowed domains found on the federation configuration for the current tenant (This list represents all the domains that the tenant is allowed to federate with). To do this, the command first calls the Get-CsTenantFederationConfiguration cmdlet to return federation information for the specified tenant. That information is then piped to the Select-Object cmdlet, which uses the ExpandProperty to "expand" the property AllowedDomains. Expanding a property simply means displaying all the information stored in that property onscreen, and in an easy-to-read format.